# How to find all HelmRelease in my cluster using java?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

After searching many of the articles, not found any answer to my problem. Hence, posting this question. I am using java spring boot. In my spring-boot application, I need to find all HelmRelease in my spring boot application. The below command, I want to execute in java and want to see the labels. Is there any SDK or java library available?

**Example in kubernates** - `kubectl get helmreleases --show-labels`

Any suggestion or help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: you tag the question with [tag:helmfile]. Are you aware that helmfile is another tech than helm?

Comment: was not aware about that. Removed the tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Java-Operator-SDK**

This is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/java-operator-sdk

**Operator-SDK**

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.github.containersolutions</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-operator-framework-starter</artifactId>
 <version>{see https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:spring-boot-operator-framework-starter for latest version}</version>
</dependency>
```

so on and so forth!

Comment: Thanks Abdennour TOUMI. Is this opensource?

Comment: It's open source, but it's for writing your own Kubernetes operators in Java. You might wanna take a look at the [fabric8 K8s client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client)

Comment: Not clear how this answers the question. How does this perform similarly to `kubectl get helmreleases`?